# why filtering on extents_tags() is slow

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Why the following command is slow (5 mins)?

```
mytable | where extent_tags() contains "20210613" | count
```

I know this is not the best way to get count , I could have used `.show table extents` and could have simply calculated `sum(RowCount)` using `summarize` operator. But I am just testing. Ideally ADX should be able to search tags across extents and get counts , so it is only metadata search and once it finds correct extent, row count is already stored as part of the extent metadata anyways, so why should it take 5 mins? And by the, the extent(s) I am interested in has the following tag:-

```
drop-by:20210613
ingest-by:20210613
```

There is a datetime field in the table which I could have used to filter too , which is what adx ideally recommends in general scenarios and I can guess the reason that min and max of every datetime field in the table is stored in every extent of the table -- but then similarly even tag is stored in every extent. So which method is more efficient , filtering on a datetime field if available or tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. you're correct that using `.show table T extents where tags contains 'string' | ...` would be much more efficient

b. as mentioned in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extenttagsfunction

> Filtering on the value of `extent_tags()` performs best when one of the following string operators is used: `has`, `has_cs`, `!has`, `!has_cs`.

c. *which method is more efficient , filtering on a datetime field if available or tags?*

The former, especially when your filter is on a substring, and not on the full content of the tag. Tags are a non-indexed metadata property of shards, and isn't an indexed data column. Also see: https://yonileibowitz.github.io/blog-posts/datetime-columns.html